# clojure priority-map how to zip

Tags: clojure, zipmap

So I am making a A* search on a eight puzzle and I need to find the neighbors of the blank tile and put them into a priority map with there Manhattan cost for example if I have.

```
(3 2 1 0 4 5 6 7 8)

which would look like [3 2 1]
                      [0 4 5]
                      [6 7 8]
```

the blank 0 tiles neighbors would be (:up :left :down)
the problem is I don't know how to make a priority-map with the neighbors and the Manhattan cost as the key. I tried using zipmap but it did not seem to work although I could have been wrong.

In the end I would like to have it in this form: (priority-map :up global Manahtten cost if moved the 3 down :down etc...

Comment: I think [partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition) may be the function you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Write a function for manhatten-cost and use priority-map-by